# Convert input () to bytes in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Since I started using version 3 of Python I have had many problems with sending string through sockets. I know that to send a string in a socket, a `'b'` must be placed before the string to convert it to bytes. But what happens when I have to convert an `input()` to bytes? How is it done?

I need to send a message written by keyboard to a socket:

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("localhost",7500))

msg = input()
client.send(msg)
```

However, when I try it, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Can someone tell me how I convert `input()` to bytes? I always use version 2.7 and I do not understand why version 3 is so irritating for the handling of sockets.  :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to `encode` you message like this:

```
msg = input().encode()
```

The reason you did not need to do this in Python 2 is because unicode strings were then their own type, but [in Python 3 all strings are now unicode by default](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit).

Answer (score 3):

To do that, you can use

```
import socket
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("localhost",7500))
msg = input()
client.send(msg.encode())
```

It returns the string encoded as a bytes object. See [str.encode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode)